# I want to delete database values from the tables as I delete the cart items. how can i do that

Tags: magento2, phtml

i want to delete the items from the table "ms_rental_products" as i click the delete button in cart. how can i do that??

```
<?php   
              function delRental()   //this is my deleting function. 
                    {
                      $objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                      $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session'); 
                      $CID =  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();

                      $objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                      $connection = $objectManager-> 
                      get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection')->
     getConnection('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION');
       $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
       $cart_id = $cart->getQuote()->getId();
       $_sku=$cart->getQuote()->getSku();
       $sqlqry = "Delete from `ms_rental_products` WHERE `customer_id`='".$CID."' and `cart_id`='".$cart_id."' and `product_sku`='".$_sku."'"; 
       $connection->query($sqlqry);}

       ?>
              <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->delRental() ?>"
              title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Remove item')) ?>"
              class="action action-delete"
               data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDeletePostJson() ?>'>
        <span>
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Remove item') ?>
        </span>
    </a>
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE.Please explain the question properly.